# 64 bit support for Google Analytics SDK (v 3.10) in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, measurement-protocol, google-analytics-sdk

I have old app containg  [Google Analytics SDK v1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v1/devguide), I am going to update my app to support 64 bit support.

I have replaced [Google Analytics SDK v1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v1/devguide) with [Google Analytics SDK v3.10](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/), (I have updated iOS SDK only not any where else in my analystic tool)

I have changed code in my appdelegate class like

```
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"XX-xxxxxx-xx"];  (ID IS OLD ONE)
```

and my View controller --> view did appear contains

```
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Class Name"] action:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Class Name"] label:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Class Name"] value:nil] build]];
```

It's not showing any data in my Analytics, I have waited two days.

I have created one Dummy testing Google Analytics account --> mobile app --> ios app, it gave me a new id.

I have replaced that new id in my code, now it's working perfectly, showing data in my new  Dummy testing Google Analytics account, But not in My live old  Google Analytics account.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem?

Comment: My only guess would be that your account is really old and something may have changed in these old accounts that is not supported by the V3.  Its an interesting question.

Comment: Thank you DalamTo , for your quick responds

Comment: Is there's any way to support 64 bit with old Google Analytics keys ?

Comment: A news about this issue? I am facing a similar problem with the measurement protocol, no data show in the GA dashboard for iOS 64 bit